# How to remove IP(s) from a text file based on given CIDR?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, cidr

To demonstrate this, I have few IPs in text file called `blocked.txt` with the following content:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
2.1.1.1
2.1.1.2
```

So given an input of CIDR of `1.1.1.0/24`

I want to remove the IP that belongs this CIDR range which are `1.1.1.1`, `1.1.1.2` and `1.1.1.3`

The only thing that makes me stuck is how to list out all the IP if CIDR form is given. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cidr_ip="1.1.1.0/24"
ip_exist=$(echo "${cidr_ip}" | grep_all_the_ip_in_that_CIDR in blocked.txt)
echo ${ip_exist} # This will list out all the iP and then I can use this to remove the IP
```

The expected output, `blocked.txt` will only have this content:

```
2.1.1.1
2.1.1.2
```

=================================

I'm testing with this data:

```
161.35.169.25
104.228.72.171
177.5.53.176
103.56.43.225
20.58.48.57
27.115.124.6
1.1.1.1
111.229.188.72
27.115.124.70
51.15.179.65
77.245.149.46
180.163.220.68
71.68.239.90
45.142.120.87
42.236.10.125
42.236.10.114
212.70.149.53
1.1.1.0/24
1.1.1.9
1.1.1.10
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
2.1.1.0/24
2.1.1.1
3.1.1.0/24
212.70.149.84
103.249.77.2
5.178.86.76
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP added few more samples to handle lines with `/` present one could try following.

```
awk -F'/' -v val="1.1.1.0/24" '
BEGIN{
  match(val,/.*\./)
  matched=substr(val,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
  split(substr(val,RSTART+RLENGTH),arr,"/")
  for(i=arr[1];i<=arr[2];i++){
   skip[matched"."i]
  }
}
!($1 in skip)
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Where variable `val` is your range of IPs.

```
awk -v val="1.1.1.0/24" '
BEGIN{
  match(val,/.*\./)
  matched=substr(val,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
  split(substr(val,RSTART+RLENGTH),arr,"/")
  for(i=arr[1];i<=arr[2];i++){
   skip[matched"."i]
  }
}
!($0 in skip)
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v val="1.1.1.0/24" '                        ##Starting awk program from here and creating variable val which has that range here.
BEGIN{                                           ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  match(val,/.*\./)                              ##using match function to match everything till . in variable val here.
  matched=substr(val,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)           ##Creating matched which has sub string of matched regex value in var variable.
  split(substr(val,RSTART+RLENGTH),arr,"/")      ##Splitting rest of value of var which is actual range into array arr here.
  for(i=arr[1];i<=arr[2];i++){                   ##Running for loop from 1st item value to 2nd item value of array here.
   skip[matched"."i]                             ##Creating skip array which has index as matched(variable) dot and i here, it contains which ips to be negleted basically.
  }
}
!($0 in skip)                                    ##In main block of program checking condition if current line is NOT present in skip then print that line.
' Input_file                                     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Going to test now.

Comment: @KalibZen, answers will given as per shown samples only, sorry but changing details later in question is not encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: No, I dont change any question only the sampe data, it didn't go through. Posted the sample data.

Comment: @KalibZen, ok so it means there are few lines with `/` in it and its not matching them right? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: You are correct, it didn't match with the line with `/`

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending time helping and with that code comment I really appreciate it. works perfectly.

Comment: Hey sorry I have an optional question for this awk method, is there a switch to invert the result ? Instead of deleting is it possible to display the IPs to be deleted?

Comment: @KalibZen, please change from `!($1 in skip)` to `($1 in skip)` and it should work then.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is by using nmap which support CIDR notation:

```
nmap -sn -v 1.1.1.0/24 | awk '/^Nmap scan/ { print $5 }' > ipadds.txt
```

Run nmap on the CIDR range doing a simple ping scan with -v to display hosts that may be down also. Use awk to strip everything but the IP addresses, outputting them to a file ipadds.txt

```
grep -v -f ipadds.txt blocked.txt
```

Do an inverse search of blocked.txt using the entries in ipadds.txt.

NOTE - The solution may not be for everyone and will be dependant on network governance and your ability to use network scanning tools. You will also need sudo permissions to run nmap to ensure that the most optimal, accurate results are attained.

Comment: Thanks for this solution but I got a lot of error such as: `sendto in send_ip_packet_sd: sendto(6, packet, 28, 0, 1.1.1.1, 16) => Operation not permitted
Offending packet: ICMP [IP > 1.1.1.1 Echo request (type=8/code=0) id=64823 seq=0] IP [ttl=59 id=34471 iplen=28 ]`

Comment: Yeah. Looks like ICMP is being blocked on ylur network. Not a solution in your case then but maybe a solution for someone else.